# Loading data from MongoDB into React State

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

I have a problem where I can load the user data from my node server, but when I try to get the data into State in the frontend of React, I get a 404 when I call the data.

error: http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)

I have tried several approaches but it seems that my issue lies in not being able to pre-load the data from the database into State....can anyone please tell me what I'm missing?

Routes/API

```js
// @route   GET api/users
// @desc    Get Users
// @access  Public
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then on the frontend, I have an action

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  GET_USERS,
  GET_USERS_ERROR
} from './types';

// Get users
export const getUsers = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/users');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_USERS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_USERS_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.status.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

My reducer file:

```js
import {
  GET_USERS,
  GET_USERS_ERROR
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  users: [],
  error: {},
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const {
    type,
    payload
  } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: payload,
      };
    case GET_USERS_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

finally, the place where I'm trying to get the data

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import {
  connect
} from 'react-redux';
import {
  getUsers
} from '../../actions/users';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

//Bootstrap Table
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

const UserTable = ({
  getUsers,
  users
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const columns = [{
      dataField: '_id',
      text: 'ID'
    },
    {
      dataField: 'user_id',
      text: "User's ID"
    },
    {
      dataField: 'firstname',
      text: 'Title of Todo'
    },
    {
      dataField: 'lastname',
      text: 'Is this done?'
    },
  ];

  return ( <
    div > Hello < /div>
    // <BootstrapTable
    //   keyField='id'
    //   data={users}
    //   columns={columns}
    //   pagination={paginationFactory()}
    // />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  users: state.users,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getUsers
})(UserTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this bit in you question   `// @route   GET api/users`, indicates you are likely missing `/api` in the FE call.

Try

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/users');
```